# How to group dates of a month in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have daily data for the month of July, August and September. I want to group data from 1st of a month into one group and from 16 till end of month into another group and  similarly for other months. Currently i am using `as.numeric(a$date-a$date[1]) %/% 15`  but it is not considering all dates like if a month has 32 days it will take only till 30th and 31-32 will be counted into next month. So is there a possible way to group dates exactly into two different group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data frame is called `df`. Then:

```
df$group <- with(df, ifelse(lubridate::day(date) <= 15, "first", "second"))
```